# graphql is emtpy when using integrated mode

Tags: jss, graphql

I have a GraphQL to fill in my menu. When I use `jss start:connected` it works just fine, but when I deploy (`jss deploy app`) and get it from the server it's empty.

I have been digging a bit into what's happening and it seems like the cache is not filled out correctly. In the source I get from the server the script tag `_jss_state__` is filled out with:

```
"APOLLO_STATE":{"ROOT_QUERY":{"item({\"path\":\"\u002Fsitecore\u002Fcontent\u002Fxlbygg\u002Fhome\"})":null,"item({})":null}}}
```

As you can see the item for both paths are null. The item should have been filled out something like this:

```
[{"data":{"item":{"name":"home","displayName":"home","pageTitle":{"value":"","__typename":"TextField"},"__typename":"AppRoute","children":[{"name":"generelt","id":"C9184E8651DC5B8889978E60C856AEC3","hideInMenu":...
```

I have now reset the cache in `GraphQlClientFactory.js`

```
export default function (endpoint, ssr, initialCacheState) {
    initialCacheState = {
        ROOT_QUERY:
        {

        }
    };
```

And at least the client gets data, but I thought the point of `SSR` was to fill in this information on the server side?

How do I get the `ROOT_QUERY` populated correctly on the server side?

Edit: 
I have modified one of my queries to contain the content from query.graphql from the sample project and then it works. But if I switch out the content of the file with my own query, it stops working. Is this a bug or something I don't understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was language, this is not defined in the default [site].config of the react app. Turns out integrated mode defaulted to en, while the test url (.no domain) defaulted to nb-NO. After setting language="nb-NO" on the site in the config file. Everything started working.